# What does it mean compute spectra of Center of Press?

Tags: frequency-spectrum

Recently, I studied a paper called "What Does Your Chair Know About Your Stress Level?

It can be download at the link below.

> http://www.barnrich.ch/wiki/data/media/pub/2010_what_does_your_chair_know_about_your_stress_level.pdf

at page 209, 
Section IV-A mentioned that

> In order
>   to characterize the movement properties of the CoP, we have
>   computed the corresponding spectra over the experiment stages
>   3–7. Fig. 5 shows the spectra of the norm of the CoP

I can understand that the meaning of Fig.4.
However, I don't understand what does Fig.5 mean.
How did they compute "the norm of the CoP" to "the spectra of the norm of the CoP"?
And what does the graph's axis mean?

Thank you.

Comment: CoP is a proxy for c.g. location, which, for living humans, moves over time.  If it moves, there may also be tangential forces, which changes the angle of the CoP.  Plot position as a function of time, and you can analyze that relationship.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, Can you describe more detail about Fig.5?  Especially,the x-axis and y-axis mean. And what spectra in this case mean.